# Use an array of Specific sheet names to update cell values VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops

I have a report that I am building where I will be inserting data from 3 different queries. Our reporting tool does not name all columns when exported as a CSV (column names are actually merged in the reporting system). I'd like to use a Macro to add the header row descriptions back in for the individual columns, but I am running into trouble getting this done.

I am attempting to use an array and a loop to accomplish this. The worksheet names and cell references within them will remain static as I refresh the report. I will have more than just these worksheets in the workbook, so I only want to "target" the specific data sheets with this macro. The macro errors out at the line immediately proceeding `with worksheets(count)`. Error code '424' "Object Required". I assume its because Excel is not "seeing" my array value as a sheet name, but I am not sure how to convert this.

I am open to more efficient way's of approaching this task.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Sub Headerfill()

    ' Headerfill Macro
    ' Macro to fill in blanks in header row from data dump

    Dim WorkSheets As Variant
    Dim Count As Integer

    WorkSheets = Array( _
        "Sheets(""VH Own Brand Component"")", _
        "Sheets(""VH Sales and Inventory Component"")", _
        "Sheets(""VH Comp Sales Component"")")

    Count = 0
        Do While Count < 3

            With WorkSheets(Count)
                .Range("B3").Value = "A Name"
                .Range("D3").Value = "B Name"
                .Range("F3").Value = "C Name"
                .Range("H3").Value = "First"
                .Range("I3").Value = "Last"
                .Range("K3").Value = "VName"
            End With

        Count = Count + 1
        Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I (and most everyone) wouldn't recommend using `Worksheets` or `Count` as a variable name, since these are special words within VBA.  I tend to use `ws` for worksheets, then something like `theCount` for your `Count`.

Comment: thanks, good call out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited per comments. This should render sheet order or name changes moot. Function taken from [Chip](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RenameProblems.aspx). See MSDN for [codename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) property.

```
Sub Headerfill()

Dim ws As Variant
Dim wsCode As Worksheet

ws = Array(4, 5, 7)

For i = 0 To UBound(ws)
Set wsCode = getCodeName("Sheet" & ws(i))

        With wsCode
            .Range("B3").Value = "A Name"
            .Range("D3").Value = "B Name"
            .Range("F3").Value = "C Name"
            .Range("H3").Value = "First"
            .Range("I3").Value = "Last"
            .Range("K3").Value = "VName"
        End With

    Next

End Sub

Function getCodeName(codeName As Variant) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets
        If StrComp(ws.codeName, codeName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set getCodeName = ws
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ws
End Function
```

Comment: I recommend perhaps not using `Count` as a variable name, since it's also a VBA function (i.e. `Worksheets.Count`).  Might it be better to put the worksheet names into the array? What happens if he rearranges his worksheets, before running the macro? The info. could get misplaced.

Comment: It's not actually been used XD Forgot it was still there ^_^; But very valid point. Hence why I changed the other variable name.

Comment: Its possible that the worksheet order may change. I'd like to leave it static, but can't guarantee.

Comment: I think this answer would work, but I would prefer to use sheet names in case the workbook order was altered.

Comment: @findwindow - If you leave it like you have the code, it's not constant.  To do that, I think you'd just need to create a variable for each sheet first (i.e. `Set firstSheet = Worksheets(1))`, then you can move the sheets around without confusion in the variable.

Comment: @ChrisG - The above code works, just replace `ws = Array(3, 4, 5)` with `ws = Array("VH Own Brand Component", "VH Sales and Inventory Component", "VH Comp Sales Component")`. The rest of the code works the same.

Comment: And it was that simple. Thanks @BruceWayne and Findwindow for your help!

Comment: Update renders sheet name or order changes irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to include BruceWaynes suggestions to keep inline with original intent of code. Findwindow's suggestions were also good, but choose to go with the answer below. Also discovered that one of my worksheets I was referencing had ellipses completing the worksheet name (due to length) vs. the full name of the report I was exporting, causing a subscript error until I corrected.

```
Sub Headerfill()

' Headerfill Macro
' Macro to fill in blanks in header row from data dump

Dim WS As Variant
Dim i As Integer

WS = Array(_
"VH Own Brand Component",_
"VH Sales and Inventory Compo...",_
"VH Comp Sales Component")


    For i = 0 To UBound(WS)

        With WorkSheets(WS(i))
            .Range("B3").Value = "A Name"
            .Range("D3").Value = "B Name"
            .Range("F3").Value = "C Name"
            .Range("H3").Value = "First"
            .Range("I3").Value = "Last"
            .Range("K3").Value = "VName"
        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: lol if you're going to uncheck my answer, at least check yours?

Comment: Sorry &#128531; @findwindow I rechecked it. Didn't realize I removed it.